# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un atributo con Jsoup y mostrar su valor tantas veces como aparece?

Tags: java, html, android, web-scrapping

Estoy haciendo una aplicación Android, con android studio y usando Java y Jsoup para la extracción de datos. Me he encontrado con el problema de que quiero extraer el valor de un atributo que se encuentra en distintas celdas de una tabla y mostrar su valor.

Lo que he tratado de hacer es: 
[image: como obtengo los datos]

Y lo que obtengo es
[image: lo que se muestra por consola al ejecutar]

Lo que realmente quiero obtener es
[image: las etiquetas de la web donde extraigo los datos]

Precisamente lo que necesito es obtener los valores del atributo title de forma similar al precio, pero no entiendo por qué me muestra solo uno.

Comment: Una pregunta cerrada no es lo mismo que una pregunta con respuesta aceptada. Son conceptos muy distintos aquí. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por cierto, el código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno finalmente di con la solución al problema
El metodo .attr() nos obtiene solamente el primer nombre del atributo title que quiero obtener, mi idea para solucionar esto ha sido crear 3 objetos detalleSuperStr y recorrer los elementos con un for para obtener el valor que quiero en cada caso
Sería de la siguiente forma:

```
detallePrecioStr =data.select("td.price").text();

            int size=data.size();


            for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
                detalleSuperStr1=data.select("tr>th>i").select("i[class~=i-ss]").eq(0).attr("title");
                detalleSuperStr2=data.select("tr>th>i").select("i[class~=i-ss]").eq(1).attr("title");
                detalleSuperStr3=data.select("tr>th>i").select("i[class~=i-ss]").eq(2).attr("title");
            }
```

De esta forma obtengo los 3 primeros titles del html que es lo que en este caso buscaba